# Loading data in model + progressbar using thread in QT

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, qt

I'm struggling using threading my app.
Some data is imported adn displayed in a tableview.
I alsdo have a running progressbar but when i import the data the bar has some interruptions.
So i would like to have the import and the progressbar running in seperate threads.
I've been reading about asyncio , Thread , Qthread , threadpool , ...
If i understand QT the mainwindow is running its own thread so any have duty should be run seperately ?

What is the correct way to go about this ?

Thx , John

[image: gui]

```
    import time
    import csv
    pd.set_option('display.width', 320)
    pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 40)
    from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
    
    
    class PandasFilterModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
        def __init__(self, df, parent=None):
            QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
            self._df = df.copy()
    
        def toDataFrame(self):
            return self._df.copy()
    
        def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant()
    
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                try:
                    return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError, ):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                try:
                    # return self.df.index.tolist()
                    return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError, ):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
    
        def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant()
    
            if not index.isValid():
                return QtCore.QVariant()
    
            return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))
    
        def setData(self, index, value, role):
            row = self._df.index[index.row()]
            col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
            if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
                # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
                value = value.toPyObject()
            else:
                # PySide gets an unicode
                dtype = self._df[col].dtype
                if dtype != object:
                    value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
            self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
            return True
    
        def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
            return len(self._df.index)
    
        def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
            return len(self._df.columns)
    
        def sort(self, column, order):
            colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
            self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
            self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
            self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
            self.layoutChanged.emit()
    
    
class ThreadClass(QThread):
    any_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    work_signal = pyqtSignal(pd.DataFrame)
    StatusUpdate = pyqtSignal(str)
    stop_signal = pyqtSignal(int)


    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.is_running = True

    @pyqtSlot(pd.DataFrame)
    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...', self.index)

        if self.index == 2:
            print("thread2")
            cnt = 0
            while (True):
                cnt += 1
                if cnt == 99: cnt = 0
                time.sleep(0.01)
                self.any_signal.emit(cnt)

        if self.index == 1:
            start = timeit.default_timer()

            # self.file1 = root_dir + "/2018DATA.csv"
            # self.file1 = root_dir + "/klanten.csv"
            self.file1 = root_dir + "/FACT2018.csv"

            # self.file1 = root_dir + "/snippets/qt_thread_updater/testfiles/2018DATA.csv"
            # self.file1 = root_dir + "/snippets/qt_thread_updater/testfiles/FACT2018.csv"
            # self.file1 = root_dir + "/snippets/qt_thread_updater/testfiles/klanten.csv"
            # self.file4 = root_dir + "/snippets/qt_thread_updater/testfiles/PRODUCTS_FULL.csv"

            # csv info weergeven
            rows = sum(1 for line in open(self.file1)) - 1  # Calculate number of rows in file
            d = ';'
            f = open(self.file1, 'r')
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=d)
            self.csv_col = len(next(reader))
            f.close()
            self.csv_rows = str(rows)
            self.df = pd.DataFrame()

            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.file1, sep=";", engine='python', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
            self.df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

            self.model = PandasFilterModel(self.df)
            self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
            self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)

            self.work_signal.emit(self.df)

            end = timeit.default_timer()
            print("Visualisation time: ", (end - start))


            print("thread1")
    
class ImportWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ImportWindow, self).__init__()

        self.thread = {}
        ui_file = root_dir + "/snippets/qt_thread_updater/test.ui"
        self.ui = loadUi(ui_file, self)

        self.client_file = root_dir + "/files/datafiles/clients.pkl"
        self.products_file = root_dir + "/files/datafiles/clients.pkl"

        # self.ui.tableData1.clicked.connect(self.tableDataClicked)
        self.ui.cmdLoad1.clicked.connect(self.ImportLoadData)
        self.ui.cmdStart.clicked.connect(self.StartProgressBarLong)
        self.ui.cmdStop.clicked.connect(self.StopProgressBarLong)
        self.ui.cmdRunCode.clicked.connect(self.RunCode)
        self.ui.cmdTest.clicked.connect(self.TestStuff)

    def RunCode(self):
        print("Start TestStuff\n")

        run_command = self.ui.txtRunCode.toPlainText()
        print("Running script: \n",run_command)

        exec(run_command)

        print(run_command)

        print("\nStop TestStuff")

    def TestStuff(self):

        print("Start TestStuff\n")

        print("\nStop TestStuff")

    def StartProgressBarLong(self):

        self.thread[2] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=2)
        self.thread[2].start()
        self.thread[2].any_signal.connect(self.pb_function)

    def StopProgressBarLong(self):

        self.thread[2].stop()
        self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(0)

    def pb_function(self, counter):
        cnt = counter
        index = self.sender().index
        if index == 1:
            self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(cnt)
        if index == 2:
            self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(cnt)
        if index == 3:
            self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(cnt)

    def ImportLoadData(self,file):

        print('Start ImportLoadData\n')
        # start = timeit.default_timer()

        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].work_signal.connect(self.table_load_function)

        print('\nStop ImportLoadData')

    def table_load_function(self,model):
        print("start table_load_function")
        self.model = PandasFilterModel(model)
        self.ui.tableData1.setModel(self.model)

        self.thread[1].stop()
        # self.ui.progressBar1.setValue(0)
        print("stop table_load_function")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle("Fusion")
        main = ImportWindow()
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi all, i made some progress ,  i updated the code, the progressbar is running in a thread and filling the table also ,  the app stays responsive , the progressbar is running but still some small interruptions , any ideas how to improve the code so the PB isn't affected at all ?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be sweet to have an option  like “run_in_thread” to be put at the beginning of a function 